# Hibernate + spring get up-to-date lazy 1 to N property value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have following property in `@Entity User`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<Friendship> getOwnedFriendships() {
    return ownedFriendships;
}
//other side:
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
```

The code `Set<Friendship> res = currentUser.getOwnedFriendships();` works correctly in my servlet until removing a `Friendship` from database using `FriendshipDao`*(by some other reference - not a reference from the set returned above)*:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Override
public void remove(Friendship toRemove) {
    if(!toRemove.isNew()) {
        em.remove(toRemove);
    }
}
```

The subsequent calls to `getOwnedFriendships()` returns always the same(*old*) results not matter what is actually in the Database at the moment. The values does not get updated until user logs in/out. How do I get correct and up-to-date ownedFriendships?

---

I have a suspicion that hibernate property

```
<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
```

is causing the trouble, because "manual" SQL queries returns up-to-date data. Disabling this or hardcoding SQL query strings does not seem to solve the problem, because the first would cause lazyInitializationException (currentUser was automatically detached by the time `ownedFriendships` are accessed) and the latter would mean bypassing both Hibernate and Spring(more or less) which would probably be a bad design(?) - I would prefer configuring the frameworks/dao/domain over any "manual" solution.

---

**Edit:** It turns out the problem(or one of the problems) was that `currentUser` was stored in session:

```
public User getCurrentUser(HttpSession session)
{
    return session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_ATTR);
}
```

when I re-queried the user instead:

```
public User getCurrentUser(HttpSession session)
{
    return userManager.findUserByName((String)session.getAttribute(USERNAME_ATTR));
```

the `Set<Friendship> res = currentUser.getOwnedFriendships();` returned up-to-date results. *(Is getting new entity instance required before querying any lazy properties?)*

Comment: If any other code parts are relevant to this question, please let me know in comments.

Comment: Does `em.remove(toRemove);` really succeed? It guess `toRemove` is a detached instance unless the transaction started by the caller of the `remove()` method is propagated to the service layer. Passing a detached instance to `EntityManager#remove()` causes the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown. You are supposed to maintain bidirectional relationships on your own which the JPA provider itself is not responsible for and that you are currently not maintaining. Finally, if you are really passing `HttpSession` to the service layer, then it is a serious design flaw.

Comment: @Tiny thanks for the feedback with service layer but what would be the correct way of finding who the current user is? To the first question: the `em.remove(toRemove);` succeeds (I even checked the database), the `toRemove` is not detached instance at the time. (I am not using any of instances from `Set<Friendship> res` as argument but a new one. To add more details the `toRemove` was fetched by key in different servlet named `RemoveFriend` and removed there, the set is queried in servlet `FriendList`)

Comment: I do not know where the `getCurrentUser()` method is defined but if it is defined on the service layer maintaining business logic, then only the required parameters should be passed to the service layer from the web layer (controller) i.e. not the entire HTTP session but only `session.getAttribute(USERNAME_ATTR)` in this case. The service layer should completely be independent of any dependencies from the web layer (`javax.servlet`). (The web layer can only be loosely-coupled with the service layer).

Comment: @Tiny Yes, it was defined in service layer(Authentication service to be precise). I moved it as protected to superclass of all my servelets - I presume it is design-wise correct now, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you have bidirectional relations between your entities, it's your responsibility to maintain both sides. So, you need to remove the `Friendship` from `User` before deleting it from the database. Try this

```
@Override
public void remove(Friendship toRemove) {
    if(!toRemove.isNew()) {
        toRemove.getOwner().getOwnedFriendships().remove(toRemove);
        em.merge(toRemove.getOwner());
        em.remove(toRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution did not helped - currently it seems if the `getOwnedFriendships` was ever queried on entity instance it will remain the same no matter what. Getting new instance of `User` entity instead helped, I am not sure, however, if that is the correct solution(?).